# How to fix empty semantic media wiki query results after restore?

Tags: restore, semantic-mediawiki

After restoring a semantic media wiki installation from backup the SMW engine does no longer return any query results. I have (re)inserted all regular pages, all form pages, all property pages into the new MW instance. So all content is there but query results remain empty. It seems as the internal data structures maintained by SMW are not filled. How can this be fixed? Are there any specific scripts that need to be run manually?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the internal SMW cache is not filled after restore. The solution is simple: You need to go to `extensions/SemanticMediaWiki/maintenance` and run the script `rebuildData.php` which will reparse every single Wiki page and fill the SMW database accordingly.

Be aware that for this to work your Wiki needs to be configured properly. By default SMW will not process additional namespaces! You need to enable this manually for every single namespace you add yourself in `LocalSettings.php` **after** the line where you enable SMW in this file. (This configuration will only have effect if you do this **after** the line that enables SMW.)